# Prevent postback on button click and multiple client function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, postback

I have an asp.net button to update database

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="SaveChanges" OnClick="btnSave_Click"
        CssClass="saveButton" ValidationGroup="answer" OnClientClick="return ValidateUserNameBeforeSubmitting();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=TextUserName.ClientID%>").blur(function () {
            ValidateUserNameAfterBlur();
        });
    });

    function ValidateUserName() {
        var returnValue;
        $.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url: "../UserNameWebService.asmx/ValidateUserName",
            data: JSON.stringify({ strUsername: $("#<%=TextUserName.ClientID%>").val() }), 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                returnValue=data.d;
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
        return returnValue;
    }
    // to prevent postback when click save button. 
    function ValidateUserNameBeforeSubmitting() {
        var isValid = ValidateUserName();
        return isValid;
    }

    function ValidateUserNameAfterBlur() {
        var isValid = ValidateUserName();
        $('#TextUserNameError').toggle(!isValid);
    }
</script>
```

The function is to validate a textbox for an username. But I have a few textbox to be validated.
Each one will display different error. Can I have multiple client side call on the button?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by __Can I have multiple client side call on the button?__

Comment: I want something like OnClientClick="return function1(),return function2()" etc. oR OnClientClick1=... OnClientClick2=...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can have multiple client-side functions:

```
$("#<%=TextUserName.ClientID%>").blur(function () {
    ValidateUserNameAfterBlur();
    ValidatePasswordAfterBlur();
    ValidateFoo();
    PhoneYourWife();
    ...
});
```

---

If you want to submit only when they are all valids:

```
$("#<%=btnSave.ClientID%>").click(function () {
    if (ValidateUserNameAfterBlur() &&
        ValidatePasswordAfterBlur() &&
        ValidateFoo()               &&
        PhoneYourWife())

    submitTheData();
});
```

Comment: This is only blurring on TextUserName textbox, but I have other textbox to be blurred.

Comment: @Love. O.K. attach those textboxes blur callbacks, where is the problem?

Comment: How about ValidateUserNameBeforeSubmitting, I need several similar functions for different textbox? How can we put them together?

Comment: @Love. I'm having real difficulties understanding your needs.

Comment: You are right. But my submitting data is in code behind, which is on the server side. What kind of code likely?